# Nesting messages on channel view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, windows-7

I'm trying to show all messages that belong to each channel on that channels index pages, is there a simple way to do this?

```
    class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
    @messages = @channel.messages
  end

  def new
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
    @message = @channel.messages.build
  end

  def create
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
    @message = @channel.messages.build(params[:message])
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created message."
      redirect_to channel_url(@message.channel_id)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    if @message.update_attributes(params[:message])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated message."
      redirect_to channel_url(@message.channel_id)
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    @message.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed message."
    redirect_to channel_url(@message.channel_id)
  end
end
```

&

```
    class ChannelsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @channels = Channel.find(:all)
  end

  def show
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
    @message = Message.new(:channel => @channel)
  end

  def new
    @channel = Channel.new
  end

  def create
    @channel = Channel.new(params[:channel])
    if @channel.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created channel."
      redirect_to @channel
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
    if @channel.update_attributes(params[:channel])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated channel."
      redirect_to @channel
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
    @channel.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed channel."
    redirect_to channels_url
  end
end
```

&

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :channels , :has_many => :messages, :shallow => true
  resources :messages , :only => [:index]
  root :channels

  resources :users, :user_sessions
  match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
  match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  #root :to => 'channels#index', :as => :listchannels



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two models Channel and Message, where a channel has many messages, you could do something like this:

```
# controller
@channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
@messages = @channel.messages

# index.html.erb
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <%=h message.content %><br>
<% end %>
```

where `content` is some attribute of `Message`

Comment: The first part would go inside the index definition?

Comment: Yes, it would go in MessagesController#index, though this assumes you have nested resources. I see erred in the `find` -- should be `params[:channel_id]`.

Comment: I'm no sure if this will work with my controllers, i'll link them above

Comment: You'll need to specify nested resources in `routes.rb` so that the URL  looks like /channels/1/messages. Then you can add the `find` on Channel as I showed above.

Comment: Im still stuck im unable to view my messages controller , therefore I cant even text if my channels controller is working. I will modifie code above with my new code. when ever i go to localhost/messages i get couldnt find channel without id.

Comment: You haven't defined nested resources. Look in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, section 2.7, for a description of this. You'll want to nest `:messages` within `:channels`.